# Python: Symmetric Encryption with GPG and Subprocess

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm trying to achieve the functionality provided by the following bash command in Python.

```
echo "$DATA" | gpg --symmetric --armor --batch --passphrase "${KEY}"
```

So far I've tried to use `subprocess` but am having difficulty passing in the data. I tried giving it as a command in the list of parameters to send to `subprocess` but that just effectively echos the the entire thing.

```
cmd = f"| gpg --symmetric --armor --batch --passphrase {key}".split()                                                  
temp = ["echo", f"\"{data}\""]
temp.extend(cmd)                                                                                                                      
res = subprocess.run(temp, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)                                                          
encrypted = res.stdout.strip()
```

I'm also interested in using the [python-gnupg](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/) module but have not yet figured out how to replicate the above with it either.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `input` argument to `run()`/`check_output()`:

```
from getpass import getpass
import subprocess

key = getpass("KEY: ")
data = b'Symmetric Encryption with GPG and Subprocess'
command = ["gpg", "--symmetric", "--armor", "--batch", "--passphrase", key]

out = subprocess.check_output(command, input=data, universal_newlines=False)
```

Note that GNU `echo` will, by default, append a newline.  Use `echo -n` to not print the trailing `\n`.  Either way, you'll want to be careful to mimic this in Python.

Comment: The `input` argument was what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering, I also got the `python-gnupg` module to work for my application. I am sticking with the `subprocess` answer since that reduces dependencies but wanted to share this as well.

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG()                                                                                                                     
encrypted = str(gpg.encrypt(data, recipients=None, symmetric=True, passphrase=key, extra_args=["--batch"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `python-gnupg` module has a long history with serious security flaws, many of which it's more likely to be affected by due to the decision to use `subproess` to call an external binary executable.

Instead, the recommendation of the GnuPG Project is to use the CPython bindings for the GPGME C API, which ship with the GPGME source code.

```py
import gpg
from getpass import getpass

key = getpass("KEY: ")
c = gpg.Context(armor=True)
data = b"Symmetric encryption with GPGME."

ciphertext, result, sign_result = c.encrypt(data, sign=False, passphrase=key)
with open("some_file.txt.asc", "wb") as f:
    f.write(ciphertext)
```

Because this uses symmetric encryption, there won't be a digital signature included and there are no recipient keys to check for.  Which means both `result` and `sign_result` will return `None`.  Only `ciphertext` contains anything and that's the ASCII armoured excrypted data, which can be written to a file as above, or you can do something else with it.

The documentation for this, far superior, module is included with the GPGME source, but an online draft version is [available here](http://files.au.adversary.org/crypto/gpgme-python-howto.xhtml).